# Trying to set unmatched parenthesis as incorrect input , doesn't work in SML

Tags: parsing, sml, smlnj

I'm writing a calculator in SML .

In my program I work with the below parenthesis :

```
{ }    (* highest priority *) 

[ ]    (* middle priority *) 

( )    (* weakest priority *)
```

When user enters a string such as :

```
calc "1+(2*3)"   (* that's ok *)
```

but those :

```
 calc "1+[2*3)"   (* Not Ok *) 

 calc "1+(2*3}"   (* Not Ok *) 

 calc "1+{2*3]"   (* Not Ok *)
```

are not , since the opened bracket does not match its closing bracket .

I tried to write that in SML , but it doesn't work . What I want do when the user enter 
an expression with unbalanced parenthesis , is to return `-1` or present error message

Here's the code :

```
signature ScannerForExp = sig
  datatype token = 
                    (* parenthesis *)

                   Lpar3             (* { *)
                 | Rpar3             (* } *)
                 | Lpar2             (* [ *)
                 | Rpar2             (* ] *)  
                 | Lpar              (* ( *)
                 | Rpar              (* ) *)

                    (* operations *)

                 | Multiply          (* * *)
                 | Div               (* / *)
                 | Plus              (* + *)
                 | Minus             (* - *)
                 | Modulo            (* % *)
                 | Power             (* ^ *)                 
                 | Num of int        (* [0-9]+ *)
                 | Undef of string   (* undefined *)
  val scanner : string -> (token list)
end;



    | #"{"::r => if s = "" then (Lpar3,r) else (toToken s,c::l)
    | #"}"::r => if s = "" then (Rpar3,r) else (toToken s,c::l)     
    | #"["::r => if s = "" then (Lpar2,r) else (toToken s,c::l)
    | #"]"::r => if s = "" then (Rpar2,r) else (toToken s,c::l)
    | #"("::r => if s = "" then (Lpar,r) else (toToken s,c::l)
    | #")"::r => if s = "" then (Rpar,r) else (toToken s,c::l)
```

And this is the function that handle this :

```
 fun E l = E2 l
  and F l
      = case l of 
          (Num n)::l1 => (NumNode n,l1)
        | Lpar::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1  in case l2 of Rpar::l3 => (en,l3)


        | Lpar2::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1 in case l2 of Rpar2::l3 => (en,l3)


        | Lpar3::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1 in case l2 of Rpar3::l3 => (en,l3)



    ...
...
(* more code *)
```

But when I try to add a rule that consists of `Lpar` with `Lpar2` or  `Lpar` with `Lpar3` :

```
  fun E l = E2 l
  and F l
      = case l of 
          (Num n)::l1 => (NumNode n,l1)
        | Lpar::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1  in case l2 of Rpar::l3 => (en,l3)


        | Lpar2::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1 in case l2 of Rpar2::l3 => (en,l3)


        | Lpar3::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1 in case l2 of Rpar3::l3 => (en,l3)


        (* a ( with a ] *)
        | Lpar::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1  in case l2 of Rpar2::l3 => raise exception
```

I get :

```
stdIn:5875.9-5903.34 Error: match redundant and nonexhaustive
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: What is the point of different "priorities" for parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is a bit off, but it looks like the code you've already got should raise a `ParserForExp` exception when the parentheses don't match.

With your "new" code, the error happens because you have two `Lpar::l1` cases, which makes one of them redundant.
I believe you need to move the mismatching parentheses cases:

```
| Lpar::l1 => let val (en,l2) = E l1  in 
                    case l2 of Rpar::l3 => (en,l3)
                             | Rpar2::l3 => [raise mismatched parentheses]
                             | Rpar3::l3 => [raise mismatched parentheses]
                             | _ => raise ParserForExp 
                    end
```